# How can a guarantee one ajax call is complete before calling another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am working on a flask application and there is this javascript function associated with a form

```
function applyQueries() {
        // does some things
        if(currentCatalog != ''){
            addCatalogFilters(currentCatalog);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  "/applyQueries",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success:function(response){ 
                        // does some stuff here
        })
}
```

The addCatalogFilters() function is also an ajax call. Both these calls change some variables in the python side of things. What I want to know is if the first ajax call (in addCatalogFilters), is guaranteed to execute and return before the second one. I am ending up with weird results that appear to be race conditions based on the order the ajax calls execute. Is this possible with code structured like this? Also if so, how can I fix it?

```
    // Add user catalog filters
    function addCatalogFilters() {
        catalog = currentCatalog;
        formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('catalogFilterForm'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  "/addCatalogFilters",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response){
                document.getElementById(catalog + 'close').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById(catalog + 'check').style.display = 'none';
                addBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("addBtn");
                removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("removeBtn");
                for (i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i++) {
                    addBtns[i].style.display = "none";
                    removeBtns[i].style.display = "inline-block";
                }
            }
        })
    };
```

Comment: Pass a callback to `addCatalogFilters`? It's not guaranteed to finish first otherwise.

Comment: Or have it return the Promise, then consume it

Comment: $.ajax returns a Promise-like object that you can .then and await on

Comment: As a heads up, if you're able to get calls from multiple users (or even the same user in multiple browsers/tabs), that may cause the same weird results.  You may also want to look into server-side synchronization options...they look pretty straightforward though I am no python expert: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-sync.html

Comment: @Richard Williams please post addCatalogFilters function so that we can better help you.  In order to make sure the ajax calls happen in the correct order, a hook is required on the ajax call(s) inside addCatalogFilters.

Comment: @user120242 I added the addCatalogFilters Function

Comment: @RichardWilliams there are errors in your code that I did not fix.  It only shows how you should be using await to make sure the ajax call is finished before execution continues.  For example you have a missing closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure with success function of ajax. First call a ajax (let's say ajax1) then call another ajax call within the success function of first ajax call  (ajax1 success function).

```
addCatalogFilters(currentCatalog)
{
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  "/the-post-usl",

            success:function(response){ 

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  "/applyQueries",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success:function(response){ 
                        // does some stuff here
                });
        })
}

function applyQueries() {
        // does some things
        if(currentCatalog != ''){
            addCatalogFilters(currentCatalog);
        }

}
```

It may not be the optimum way. But guarantee one ajax call is complete before calling another.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked this obvious solution.  This worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) like this:

```
async function applyQueries() {

  if(currentCatalog !== ''){
    const filtersAdded = await addCatalogFilters(currentCatalog);
  }

  // Perform AJAX call

}
```

By usinc async/await, your code will wait until the `addCatalogFilters()` function has resolved. However, for this to work, the `addCatalogFilters()` function should be async with a return value. Something like this:

```
async function addCatalogFilters(catalog){
  // Ajax call
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  "foo",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success:function(response){ 
          return true
    })

}
```

Comment: `addCatalogFilters` should return a promise for `await` to work; it should also use the `async` keyword (although this is less important that returning a promise).

Comment: You're right. By using the `async` keyword, the return will still be wrapped inside of a promise implicitly, which should make the function awaitable

Comment: Which still isn't helpful, because he needs to await on the ajax returned Promise, not just the end of the function.  Should be explicitly noted here.

Comment: You're correct. Misread that. However, the return can be put in the success callback of the ajax request. I know an async function should always have a return value for each path, but this should return and therefore trigger the first async function upon the completion of the Ajax request

Comment: That won't work, you need a return or await in front of $.ajax.  The return true is chained into the Promise, but the Promise generated by $.ajax is never waited on by the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how applyQueries is called, you may need to have an await or .then where you call it.  Note that you can also use "result = await addCatalogFilters(currentCatalog)" to put the ajax result into a variable result that you can work with and pass to your $.ajax call in applyQueries.  I don't know the nature of your code, so I can't make any direct suggestions.

```
async function applyQueries() {
        // does some things
        if(currentCatalog != ''){
            // await on the returned Promise-like jqXHR (wait for ajax request to finish)
            // recommend assigning awaited result to a variable and passing to next $.ajax
            await addCatalogFilters(currentCatalog);
        }
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  "/applyQueries",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success:function(response){ 
                        // does some stuff here
        })
}
```

---

```
// Add user catalog filters
function addCatalogFilters() {
    catalog = currentCatalog;
    formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('catalogFilterForm'));
    // return the Promise-like jqXHR object: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  "/addCatalogFilters",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response){
            document.getElementById(catalog + 'close').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(catalog + 'check').style.display = 'none';
            addBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("addBtn");
            removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("removeBtn");
            for (i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i++) {
                addBtns[i].style.display = "none";
                removeBtns[i].style.display = "inline-block";
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await`. However, as no one has mentioned, I would like to demonstrate how you can accomplish this with `Promise`.

Lets define two functions:

```
function first_function(data) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let dataSet = [[]];

    let response;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'example.com/xyz',
      async: false,
      data: data,
      success: function (value) {
        response = value;
        dataSet = JSON.parse(response);
        resolve(dataSet)
      },

      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    });

  })

}


function second_function(data) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let dataSet = [[]];

    let response;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'example.com/abc',
      async: false,
      data: data,
      success: function (value) {
        response = value;
        dataSet = JSON.parse(response);
        resolve(dataSet)
      },

      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    });

  })

}
```

Now you can make sure that `second_function()` gets called only after the execution of `ajax` request in `first_function()` by following approach:

```
first_function(data)
  .then(dataSet => {
    //do other things
    second_function(dataSet)
      .then(dataSet2 => {
        ////do whatever you like with dataSet2

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  });
```